# Laravel - Guzzle not returning any data even though URL is correct

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, guzzle

I am trying to return the JSON data from a third party API - `http://postcodes.io/`. I currently have in my controller:

```
 $client = new Client();
    $request = $client
        ->get('https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/'.Input::get('postcode'));

    $statusCode = $request->getStatusCode();

    if ($statusCode >= 200 && $statusCode < 300) 
    {
       $json = Response::json($request); // Returns JSON decoded array of data.
    }
```

I'm trying to return the postcode information as such:

> https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/OX495NU

If I `dd($request)`, then this is printed out, with a 200 status code but with no data associated with it:

```
JsonResponse {#245 ▼
  #jsonOptions: 0
  #data: "{}"
  #callback: null
  #encodingOptions: 15
  +headers: ResponseHeaderBag {#242 ▶}
  #content: "{}"
  #version: "1.0"
  #statusCode: 200
  #statusText: "OK"
  #charset: null
}
```

Any help why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$request->getBody();`? though normally I'd do a `$response = $request->send();` and then `echo $response->getBody();`

Comment: If I add `$response = $request->send();` it presents this error - `Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response::send()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the raw response back from Guzzle and it needs to be formatted. A simple way is `$response->getBody();`.

Think of this like a collection in Laravel. When you get the data back, it is in a collection with a bunch of extra data that may be useful but if you only want the data you would run `$user->toJson();` For Guzzle, if you want to strip out all the extra curl data, the protocol info, the headers, etc, you would want only the payload, or body. `$response->getBody();`

Comment: Changing to your suggested edit, it still returns no data - `#data: "{}"`?

Comment: The URL it should be requesting prints out correctly too. If I copy it from the `dd(URL)` into my browser, it returns the JSON data I need.

Comment: Can you attempt to set up the client's configuration settings? Something like `$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/', 'verify' => false]);` then try `$response = $client->get(Input::get('postcode'));` It could be the defaults in Guzzle are incorrect.

Comment: if I `dd($reponse)`, it returns this: `Response {#250 ▼
  -reasonPhrase: "OK"
  -statusCode: 200
  -headers: array:8 [▶]
  -headerLines: array:8 [▶]
  -protocol: "1.1"
  -stream: Stream {#241 ▶}
}` Even less fields than previously?

Comment: do not dd it. `echo $response->getBody(); die();`

Comment: sorry about the response times. I am still at work and was in a meeting. This is the exact code I ran on my local and I believe it gets what you want `$client = new Client([
'base_uri' => 'https://api.postcodes.io/',
'timeout'  => 2.0,
'verify' => false
]);
$response = $client->get('postcodes/OX495NU');
echo $response->getBody(); die();`